# Problem sending data from arduino with ESP8266 to a local mysql database

Tags: esp8266, http

i'm currently trying to send a randomly generated number from Arduino via ESP8266 wifi module to a local mysql database estabilished with xampp, but having a problem with it. Here is my arduino and php receiving code. I should mention that i'm extremely unfamiliar with mysql, php, and the whole server & database things, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* server = "192.168.1.106";
const char* ssid = "DARUSALAM C8";
const char* password = "asro4520";
const char* SensorID = "ESP001";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi Connected");
}

void loop() {
float n = random(300);

Serial.print("Random Number: ");
Serial.println(n);

  if (client.connect(server,80)) {
    Serial.print("Posting data...");
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);
    Serial.println("Random Number: " + String(n));
    client.println("GET /log.php?n=" + String(n));
    client.println("HOST: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();

    client.stop();
    Serial.println();

    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
  }

  delay(5000);
}
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$db_amb = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "wemos");
if (!$db_amb) die("Gagal terkoneksi ke DB Utama. Error : " . mysqli_connect_error());

$n = $_REQUEST['n'];
if (!empty($n) &amp;&amp;)
{  
  $s = "insert into data_random set value1='$n'";
  $r = mysqli_query($db_amb, $s);
  echo "OK";
}
else echo "ERR";
?>;
```

The database is named 'wemos', and the table where i intend to store the data is named 'data_random' with 4 columns named value1-value4. My intentions is to store the random number to the 'value1' field.

**EDIT** the problem i encountered is whenever i checked `http://localhost/log.php` this appears:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\log.php on line 7
```

i have tried modifying the syntax in numerous ways but the problem presist. I suspect my code may have some underlying fundamental problem that is not syntax related, but i can't tell due to my lack of experience. Again, any help/clue is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: What sort of a problem? (Please edit the answer into the question.)

Answer (score 1):

The `HOST` should not have a newline after it, so you should have

```
client.print("HOST: ");
client.println(server);
```

In addition your PHP looks dodgy to me.  I'm not very familiar with PHP at all, but I think the `&amp;`s here are left over from something you have removed, and causing syntax errors - just remove them

```
if (!empty($n) &amp;&amp;)
```

I believe your `n` parameter is going to be in `_GET` (not `_REQUEST`).  Also, you should check whether it's there, not just assume it is, so:

```
if isset ( $_GET["n"] )
{
    $n = $_GET["n"];
    // Do your database stuff here
}
```

(You should find the PHP log (where depends on what OS your server is running on) and I think it would point you straight to this problem.  No point trying to debug it blind.)

Comment: First of all thank you for cleaning up my mess. Due to your suggestion i have removed the newline after  `HOST`. Yes, i also suspect that the `&amp;`s is what causing the syntax error because you are also correct in that i only edited someone else's program i found from browsing the internet. but now when i checked the local host i got `Notice: Undefined index: n in C:\xampp\htdocs\log.php on line 6
ERR;`. I installed xampp in windows 10, can you point out the PHP log location? thank you very much

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "checked the local host". I don't know the location of the PHP log in Windows, sorry, but I think I've seen another the mistake in your code - answer ammended.

Comment: The $_REQUEST super global should work just fine. It contains the contents _GET, _POST, and _COOKIE. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php.

Comment: You will get the index not defined error if you load the page in your browsers with out the "?n=" part. So to test the script in your browser use: http://localhost/log.php?n=123

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
client.println("GET /log.php?n=" + String(n));
client.println("HOST: ");
client.println(server);
```

To this:

```
client.print("GET /log.php?n=" + String(n));
client.println( " HTTP/1.0" );
client.print("Host: ");
client.println(server);
```

This means you're sending the `Host:` header + value on one line, and you're correctly appending the `HTTP/1.0\n` after your URL-request.